# TriggerSend - Is it possible to define whitelist of emailaddresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We invokes the SOAP API to send transactional messages using a triggered send.
Added below script to check if an email address exist in a WhitelistDE dataextension. Trigger send  verify the dataextension and send an email if it present otherwise add to error queue. Is it possible to add check at one place instead of adding this check in every email template.

```
%%[
VAR @RowCount, @email

SET @email = [Email Address]
SET @RowCount = Rowcount(LookupRows("WhitelistDE", "EmailAddress", @email))
IF @RowCount == 0 then
    RaiseError("Subcriber doesn't exist in whitelist", true)
ENDIF  
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having Triggered Send Exclusion Scripts enabled on your account by SFMC Support.  Once enabled, you'll have a script box that'll show on the Triggered Send Definition page.

All you'll need to do is write an AMPScript that returns `true` or `false`.  Something like this:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("WhitelistDE", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) == 0
```

Comment: I tried you solution by adding the below script to 'exclusion script box'. But for some how my triggered send is not taking to script into consideration. May i know why would that..? ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("My_WhiteList_DE", "EmailAddress", emailaddr))==0 Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: If you output `%%emailaddr%%` in the body of your email, what does it show?  Is that email address in `My_WhiteList_DE`?